# How do I change Magento 2 search from OR logic to AND?

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, search-terms, fulltext

How do I change Magento 2 mini search logic from OR to AND?

Right now if I search for 'Shoe laces', it returns all products with terms either 'shoe' or 'laces'.

I need a Fulltext search so that only products with full-term 'Shoe laces' are returned. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution , create a file search_request.xml in your module's etc folder ,

copy the entire   node from vendor/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/search_request.xml

and change

```
<queryReference clause="**should**" ref="search" />
```

to this

```
<queryReference clause="**must**" ref="search" />
```

do not forget to add sequence in your module file.

in case you installed your module and added  after that, just change your module version and run setup:upgrade again , thanks

Comment: Please read your answer after posting it. The code samples haven't been visible. I changed that now.

Comment: Please check this link https://www.eddiemay.me.uk/2019/06/20/magento-2-and-or-search-operators/

Comment: Hi, I followed this and now the search synonyms are not working. If I add synonyms: read,rid then searching read or rid comes up with no result. Please help.!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is looking into a working solution for Magento >2.4.0.

1. First extend `Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match` by adding this to your di.xml (`<VENDOR>/<Module>/etc/frontend/di.xml`)

```
<preference for="Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match"
                type="<VENDOR>\<Module>\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match" />
```

2. Create the file `<VENDOR>\<Module>\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match.php` and copy the content from `Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match`

In the `buildQueries()` function change the condition building (line 157) to this:

```
if($matchCondition != 'match_phrase_prefix'){
                $field = [
                    'query' => $transformedValue,
                    'boost' => $match['boost'] ?? 1,
                    'operator' => 'and'
                ];
            } else {
                $field = [
                    'query' => $transformedValue,
                    'boost' => $match['boost'] ?? 1
                ];
            }
            $conditions[] = [
                'condition' => $queryValue['condition'],
                'body' => [
                    $matchCondition => [
                        $resolvedField => $field,
                    ],
                ],
            ];
```

I created a GIST for clarification https://gist.github.com/JEreth/dd415dfc796fb6a3782f38cab022e607

Thanks for the answers above as they helped me to find this solution.

Comment: I can approve that solution works for Magento 2.4.2.
Very nice.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to set AND operator in your elastic search JSON queries, Override the `module-elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/Match.php`. file in your custom module and then The code you have to edit in the build function in line no 75

```
if($matchKey != 'match_phrase_prefix'){$matchQuery['operator'] = "AND";}
```

Also, make sure you are not setting the operator in match_phrase_prefix.

After this, you'll get exact matches in the catalog search.

This has been tested well for Magento CC 2.4.1-p1

Comment: This is not working with M2.4.1 & M2.4.2, I am usingg M2.4.2 any suggestion what is the issue

Comment: what exact error you're getting and which file are you overriding?

Answer (score 0):

those settings will not work.

make it like below:

Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\Query\Builder\Match.php

$conditions[] = [
'condition' => $queryValue['condition'],
'body' => [
$condition => [
$resolvedField => [
'query' => $value,
'boost' => isset($match['boost']) ? $match['boost'] : 1,
**'operator' => 'and',**
],
],
],
];

this will give you exact results.