# Magento2 - Search synonyms doesn't work after changing search to AND from OR

Tags: catalogsearch, magento2.2.4

I have changed the search `AND` and `OR` logic by following the link:
[[How do I change Magento 2 search from OR logic to AND?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192718/how-do-i-change-magento-2-search-from-or-logic-to-and][1])
but now the search synonyms are not working.

If I add synonyms: `read`,`rid`
then searching *read* or *rid* comes up with no result.

Please help.!

[How do I change Magento 2 search from OR logic to AND?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192718/how-do-i-change-magento-2-search-from-or-logic-to-and)