# How i can change search condition from "OR" to "AND" magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

i'm using magento 2.3.4 and mysql search

I tried search on frontend example "ABC XYZ" text, but look like it searching which incl "ABC" or "XYZ"

I would like it show result which incl "ABC XYZ"

Is there any possible way to do it? Please help me, thank all

I also tried this but not work: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/192763/77178

Comment: ABC XYZ is a product name ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom module: First, create a custom module in Magento 2. You can follow the official Magento 2 documentation to create a custom module.
2. Create a di.xml file: Next, create a di.xml file in your module's etc directory. Add the following code to it:

   ```
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\FilterMapper">
        <plugin name="change_search_condition" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Search\FilterMapper" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
   ```

This code registers a plugin that will modify the search filter.

3. Create a FilterMapper.php file: Create a FilterMapper.php file in your module's Plugin/Search directory. Add the following code to it:

   ```
        <?php
        namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Search;

        use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\FilterMapper as MagentoFilterMapper;

        class FilterMapper
        {
            public function afterBuild(MagentoFilterMapper $filterMapper, $result)
            {
                foreach ($result->getFilters() as $filter) {
                    if ($filter->getField() == 'search_term') {
                        $filter->setConditionType('and');
                    }
                }

                return $result;
            }
        }
   ```

This code modifies the search filter by setting the condition type to "and" for the "search_term" field.

4. Flush the cache: Finally, flush the cache to see the changes take effect.